# What is wrong with a simple variable mutex implementation?

Tags: mutex

I have this `lock()` `unlock()` mutex implementation:

```
void lock (boolean *m) {
 while (*m == true) {}
 *m = true;
}

void unlock (boolean *m) {
 *m = false;
}
```

Question is, what is wrong with this kind of approach. Beside obvious performance implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the mutex is initially true/locked and threads A & B have each called `lock`.  If after C `unlock`s it, A & B each check `m` before either sets `m` to true, both will get past the lock.